# Deserialize JSON to Dictionary with DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, .net-4.5

I receive the following JSON result int the response:

```
{"result": { "":-41.41, "ABC":0.07, "XYZ":0.00, "Test":0.00 }}
```

I've prepared the following class for deserializating:

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class RpcResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "result")]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>> Result { get; set; }
}
```

However when I'm tring to deserialize it with `DataContractJsonSerializer` the `Result` property ends up with having zero entries. (Also doesn't work when declaring `Result` as `Dictionary<string, decimal>`)

Is there a way to perform this with `DataContractJsonSerializer`?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string represents an object with a property Result that is itself an object with 4 properties: "", ABC, XYZ, and Test.  For result to be a list of KeyValuePairs, the JSON would look like this:

```
{"result": [{ "":-41.41}, {"ABC":0.07}, {"XYZ":0.00}, {"Test":0.00 }] }
```

Note that if you are using an associative array in Javascript code, that it is going to be serialized as an object with property-value pairs, not as an array of objects.  If that is the source of the JSON string, you may need to switch to using an ordinary indexed array in your JS to get the proper JSON.

Comment: I don't use JavaScript anywhere, and also I can't change format of the result.