# Deserialize JSON to Dictionary with DataContractJsonSerializer in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, dictionary, deserialization

I have a json string, for example

```
{"timestamp":1362463455, "features" : {"one":true, "two":false}}
```

I want to deserialize it with `DataContractJsonSerializer` to my class:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "timestamp")]
    public int Timestamp { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "features")]
    public Dictionary<string, bool> Features { get; set; }
}
```

But I have a error in process `"ArgumentException"`. I have a problems with deserialize `Dictionary`, if deserialize only timestamp then I don't have errors. I thought is dictionary most suitable structure for this. But it don't work. I checked [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980973/deserialize-json-to-dictionary-with-datacontractjsonserializer), but `Dictionary<string, object>` don't work too. 
Maybe because in example using:

```
DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings =
        new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;
```

But I can't use `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` in Windows Phone.

Sorry, if my question is double.

Thank advance.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this?

Comment: yeah, now I use Json.NET http://james.newtonking.com/json. JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);

Answer (score 0):

@Alexandr

I am writing a code for you it will help you to deserialize the object from json to yourClassCustomObject.

```
private async Task<List<MyClass>> MyDeserializerFunAsync()
{
    List<MyClass> book = new List<MyClass>();
    try
    {
       //I am taking my url from appsettings. myKey is my appsetting key. You can write direct your url.
       string url = (string)appSettings["mykey"];
       var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
       request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
       var factory = new TaskFactory();
       var task = factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse,request.EndGetResponse, null);
       var response = await task;
       Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
       string data;
       using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
       {
           data = reader.ReadToEnd();
       }
       responseStream.Close();
       DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<MyClass>));
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
       book = (List<MyClass>)json.ReadObject(ms);
       return book;
   }
}
```

Above code is working in my wp8 application it is faster you can try, it will help you. I am performing asynchronous operation but you can create your simple method with MyClass return type.